# `npm run jshint` results in `missing script: jshint`

Tags: javascript, npm, jshint

I'm trying to jshint a few javascript files, but for some reason the local npm install of jshint isn't working.

The package is there:

```
$ npm list --depth=0
testapp@1.0.0 /Users/me/workspace/testapp
└── jshint@2.9.3
```

And the error I get is the following:

```
$ npm run jshint
npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "jshint"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0

npm ERR! missing script: jshint
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/workspace/testapp/npm-debug.log
```

I can work around this with a global install, but I'd prefer to have it working locally.

Comment: Can you please try executing `sudo chown -R $(whoami) "$HOME/.npm"` before you execute `npm run jshint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) `npm run` is an alias for `npm run-script` and runs one of the `scripts` in the `package.json` file. If you add a `jshint` script entry to your `package.json`, it should run your locally-installed `jshint`:

```
{
    "name": ...,
    "version": ...,
    "scripts": {
        "jshint": "jshint"
    }
}
```